# GeoServer NetCDF loader ignores the scaling factor - how to fix?

Tags: geoserver, netcdf

I am using GeoServer 2.13.2 on an Ubuntu Trusty 14.04 Linux docker container and I have most plugins installed and certainly the NetCDF plugin.

For the most part it seems work well and I have all layers exposed and working until I discovered that the values were completely wrong when queried.

I just used the Layer Preview to test the values. The values were gigantic. After running toolsUI-4.6.jar and examining the structure I see:

```
netcdf 
 /data/weather/June2018_WindWaveSwellSSTSSPUV1.nc {
  dimensions:
    longitude = 480;
    latitude = 241;
    time = UNLIMITED;   // (241 currently)
  variables:
    float longitude(longitude=480);
      :units = "degrees_east";
      :long_name = "longitude";

    float latitude(latitude=241);
      :units = "degrees_north";
      :long_name = "latitude";

    int time(time=241);
      :units = "hours since 1900-01-01 00:00:0.0";
      :long_name = "time";
      :calendar = "gregorian";

    short sst(time=241, latitude=241, longitude=480);
      :**scale_factor = 5.742090041944516E-4**; // double
      :add_offset = 287.4019345751854; // double
      :_FillValue = -32767S; // short
      :missing_value = -32767S; // short
      :units = "K";
      :long_name = "Sea surface temperature";

    short sp(time=241, latitude=241, longitude=480);
      :**scale_factor = 0.788649718939313**; // double
      :add_offset = 78192.71700326553; // double
      :_FillValue = -32767S; // short
      :missing_value = -32767S; // short
      :units = "Pa";
      :long_name = "Surface pressure";
      :standard_name = "surface_air_pressure";

    short u10(time=241, latitude=241, longitude=480);
      :scale_factor = 0.001169629851026868; // double
      :add_offset = 3.466105248551049; // double
      :_FillValue = -32767S; // short
      :missing_value = -32767S; // short
      :units = "m s**-1";
      :long_name = "10 metre U wind component";
```

It would seem the scaling factor is being ignored.
Is there a way to add it to the index schema file or how can I correct it so the layer returns the correct values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding this flag to your JAVA_OPTS should force the low level netcdf reader to automatically apply scale and offset so that you will get scaled values back:

-Dorg.geotools.coverage.io.netcdf.enhance.ScaleMissing=true

As far as I remember, autoscaling was not default behavior to preserve backward compatibility on already configured datasets and styles before that functionality has been introduced.

We may consider using it as default in newer GS versions.

Comment: I added that to the startup.sh and restarted the server. Now nothing with netcdf works. I tried reloading the netcdf from scratch and that does not work at all when trying to add a layer. I get following error consistently: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument "value" should not be null.
 at org.geotools.util.SoftValueHashMap.ensureNotNull(SoftValueHashMap.java:125)
 at org.geotools.util.SoftValueHashMap.put(SoftValueHashMap.java:257)
 at org.geotools.coverage.io.netcdf.NetCDFReader.getGridCoverageSource(NetCDFReader.java:679)

Comment: Not sure what to do next. The netcdf comes straight from ECMWF so it should not be unusual. The ToolsUI had no problem reading and displaying the data, drawing contours and at correct scale. Any ideas?

Comment: I solved my exception problem by removing all stores related to the netcdf file, clearing all caches, locks and reloading the config. I then removed the index folder for that file. Then I readded the store pointing to that file and published the layers which now works. It is scaling correctly. I will mark as correct answer.